# How to retrieve the text of a child node only if the child node exists

Tags: java, xpath

I have to get the text of a field from the table using xpath as a part of automation testing.
The hierarchy of the field:  `<td>` is a parent node and `<span>` is the child node of `<td>` as shown below. The `<span>` node contains the text value which need to retrieved.

`<td>`
`<span>Testing</span>`
`</td>`

Xpath for above code would be: \td\span\text()

However, in some cases the `<span>` node will not be available. For example,  when the field doesn't contain any color the span node will not be available and the text value will be directly displayed under `<td>` node.

`<td>Testing</td>`

Xpath for above code would be: \td\text()

I want to write xpath in such a way that, the text value should be retrieved from `<td>` node if the child node doesn't exist, else get the value from `<span>` node if the child node exists. Could I be able to write xpath in one go using any xpath functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could get both the td, and the span. And perform a union on them. You can perform unions in xpath using the `|` operator. More info can be found [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-union-operator-example/)

Comment: I am using lengthy xpath, so I am just avoiding to increase the xpath length further. However, it would be useful if I could able to use "|" function only at specific place. For Eg: //table............./parent::tr/((\td\text())|(\td\span\text())).  But this doesn't when I use '(' keyword inappropriately. Could we fine tune this?

Comment: @TestersLogic not with XPath 1.0, and that's all that's supported by a bunch of libraries. You can do tons of things with XPath 2.0, but you'll need Saxon to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Just `/td` . When you will convert it to text, the text will be the text that was in the cell, with or without a `<span>`.

XML/HTML are designed to allow the addition of markup within text, and to completely ignore the presence of this additional markup if it is not relevant to your interest.

Comment: @TestersLogic it does for me. Post a complete, minimal and verifiable example. I need to copy/paste what you have and run it as-is, without any modification whatsoever. Then I'll be able to tell what are our differences of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two paths as demonstrated below:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class TestXPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String span = "<td>Other<span>Testing</span></td>";
        final String noSpan = "<td>Other</td>";

        final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        final DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        final XPathExpression xpathExpr = xPath.compile("/td[span]/span/text()|/td[not(span)]/text()");
        System.out.println(xpathExpr.evaluate(db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(span))), XPathConstants.STRING));
        System.out.println(xpathExpr.evaluate(db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(noSpan))), XPathConstants.STRING));
    }

}
```